# Getting following error while performing the android build?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic2

> \platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7:41-73: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')

Getting this error while building the android apk. Tried using the CompileSdkVersion = 27 , BuildToolsVersion = "26.0.2". one more thing i am not using the android studio i am just using the command line tool as sdk manager. nad my build.gradle file is look like this.

```
ext {
apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
// The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = 27;
}
// The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = "26.0.2";
}
// Sets the versionCode to the given value.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
    cdvVersionCode = 1
}
// Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
    cdvMinSdkVersion = 15
}
// Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
    cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
}
// .properties files to use for release signing.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
    cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
}
// .properties files to use for debug signing.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
    cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
}
// Set by build.js script.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
    cdvBuildArch = null
}

// Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
```

}

and my dependencies are

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+"
compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --fetch --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=23.+ --save
```

this plugin solve my problem.